# Zalgo in user names and effects on comments rendering

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, display-names, unicode

After viewing [this user name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155074/%d0%a0%d0%a1%d0%a2%c8%a2%d1%b8%d0%a4%d0%a5%d1%be%d0%a6%d0%a7%d0%a8%d0%a9%d0%aa%d0%ab%d0%ac%d1%a2%d1%a4%d0%ae%d1%a6%d1%aa%d1%a8%d1%ac%d1%a0%d1%ba%d1%ae%d1%b0%d1%b2%d1%b4) (which contains a lot of Unicode) I had the idea to test if usernames allow ZALGO. To my dismay **they do**.

Is this wanted? Together with ShadowWizard we did a quick test. ZALGO has the ability to "break" comments.

> [image]

Shouldn't that be avoided before someone start abusing it?

---

**EDIT**: little clarification: I asked around and it seems that some time ago Zalgo didn't work in usernames. So it seems that some "recent" change broke that rule. While it is true that missuses could be handled manually, it could be worth to check why the behaviour changed suddenly (assuming my sources where right).

Comment: oh. it's something related to that username again ...

Comment: You don't have to ban Zalgo in usernames. Just some `display: inline-block; overflow: hidden;` will do.

Comment: @Antony also a worth idea, and one that I could grease if they don't change it and someone start abusing. Yet, would be nice to know why it wasn't allowed before and now is.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is by-design; until there's actual evidence of a genuine problem (that isn't solved simply by communication), I'm not sure there is anything to fix. If there *was* a change, I would expect it would relate to our increasing internationalisation.

Comment: @Marc so now you allow anything in the display name?

Comment: @MarcGravell mind reposting that as answer so that I could accept it?

Comment: Can't really have discussion by design, so changed back to bug. (assuming @Marc just removed the first tag to allow the bydesign tag itself)

Comment: S͛ͮ͂͛ͣ̓̂̒͌͑c͌̄ͯ̓̇ͥͩ̔ͮͧ͋͒̇r̈ͦͫ͆̊̀e͊̊̏̆ͥ̅ͨ̂͑̂̽͋w̾ͩͬ̇ͧ̐̋̎ͫͥ̅̄̇ͫͣ̀̐ͬ̊ ̍̒ͮ̉eͦ́ͮͯͩͦ̊ͥ͑ͩͧͩͦ̔̔̚vͭͭͣͭ̇́̒ě͊ͥ͗̾̓̔̎͗̾͂̈́̍͂ͥ͌͛̚̚rͫ̽̉ͨ̾̄̍̃̌ͨͩͩy̾̎́̓͛ͭ̾̃̚t͒ͪ̄͑̀ͫͪh̉̄̂̓ͤͫͩ͌̾̑͐ͥͮǐ̓̌n̈́̌̿̋̽́͑̌̏g͒̿̈͛̔ ̈ͨͦ̿̊̉̽̇́ͩ͂͆̄̃̌̚Sͥ̏̅ͬ̽ͮ̎͋̈́ͨ̉ͤh͊̌̂̎̽̈͗̂a̍̌̂͒̇͗͗ͭ̊̃̏̾̄́d̄̓̀̏̉̾̈ͬ͌̾̊ͬͨ̇o͋ͥ͗͗̐ͨ́ͬ͐ͣ̑̀̽͋̎͊͋̚w̉̾̔̉ͤͮ͊ͯͭ̇ͯW̿ͪ̈́̂̄ͥ͑͛̄i͐̓͊̽̑͊ͬͬͥ̾̉̉̔ͭz̓̾̆ͪ̈́̊̐̆͋̀ͯ̒ͭa̋ͨ͋́ͥͨ͂̂͌ͪ̂̏rͩ̐̒̋͒̉̏̍̉̓d̓ͬ͛ͮ̓͒͆͂̓̉ͧ̔̆͂͂̚ ̉ͮ̐ͧ͛ͣͪ͛̔̋̏̆̽͛͑̿̾̚ī̉̄̄ͣ̿s̑̂̋̌ͭ͂͌̒̉ͯ̅ͨ̚ ̂͐̍̈ͬ̋̈́̎̚s̓͋ͥ̄̃ͫͫ̃͊a͆ͪ͂̆̆͋͌͆̽ͩͧͪ̋ͥy̑ͣ̋ͭ̋̃̂̊̓̾̆̃ͫ͐̽ͨ̃ͮͬi͐́͐ͤͣ̆̍̃͑͌̄̀̀͊ͥ̒͊ͧ̚n̄ͪͮͩ̈́́ͧ͗̊̆̌ͯ̽̈́̒̏ğ̉̄ͤ́ͨ̂̈́̇ͦ̅̋̅ ͨ̈ͬ͑̐̈́̅ͪ͌̐̑͋̑͐͊͐̎ǎ̈́͊̅̈́̅ͣ͛ͬ̋̓̐bͮ̄̅͐͆ͩ̐͒͂oͩ̆̓ͨv̏̾́͋̈̑͑͂è̓͂ͦ̈̌̽̌́̈̎̐.ͬ̉͛̋̉͆ͧ̇̌ͮ̐͂̔ͨ ̋͒̉ͣ̽̄̏ͪ ̽

Comment: lol, it's still funny, @Won't :D

Comment: @Won't how to generate that string.?

Comment: In principle, could someone add a diamond (♦) to the end of their name?

Comment: @WaiHaLee - not possible. The names disallow most special characters. The diamond is one of them, unicodes like "" are disallowed too (I have tried). For some reasons, Zalgo works (probably related to the way Zalgo works in the first place).

Comment: This stuff comes up more and more often. Apparently, Cthulhu has a shrine at Stack Exchange headquarters.

Comment: @DeerHunter: one name -  Shog9. Check his user welcome message on the meta chat and you will understand.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By [Marc Gravell's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247022/zalgo-in-user-names-and-effects-on-comments-rendering#comment809699_247022) this is to be considered as **by-design** and as such won't be modified unless problems emerge that make the fix worth the effort. In the meantime abuse of the system shall be dealt with manually.

Answer (score 26):

If someone uses a user name that breaks site functionality, moderators will simply change that username and ask the user to rename to something harmless. If a user intentionally continues to break the site that way, they'll be suspended. Given how rare this is likely to come up, I think handling it manually is the best choice.

Comment: Point is: based on other users some time ago it was disabled... so it seems that something broke that rule.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Zalgo will not be silenced...