# Can user names have a filter on whacky chars?

Tags: feature-request, users, display-names

Is it too much to ask that "whacky" characters be prevented from being used in user names, so we don't have users like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80243/l%CC%B2%CC%B3o%CC%B2%CC%B3%CC%B3n%CC%B2%CC%B3%CC%B3g%CC%B2%CC%B3%CC%B3p%CC%B2%CC%B3o%CC%B2%CC%B3%CC%B3k%CC%B2%CC%B3%CC%B3e%CC%B2%CC%B3%CC%B3?tab=profile) whose name renders as L̲̳o̲̳̳n̲̳̳g̲̳̳p̲̳o̲̳̳k̲̳̳e̲̳̳.

I'm all for creativity, but it mucks up pages formatting, especially when the user makes, or is mentioned in, comments. Another example, it's obscuring the reputation and badges in user card:

> [image]

Comment: Hmm, do the characters in my name count as whacky?

Comment: Nah - they are cool. I'm ok with any char from any language. It's the character sequences that deliberately render out of the line they were placed in that I have a problem with.

Comment: Do you have an example of the messed-up formatting? I've been clicking through the user's activity (on the Android app, which may render differently than various browsers) but I haven't spotted any particularly troubling cases yet.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247022/zalgo-in-user-names-and-effects-on-comments-rendering

Comment: @dmg in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470669/should-unicode-be-allowed-in-usernames#comment43432037_3470669) when rendered on chrome for iOS the whacky stuff partially obscures the next line. It's not a big deal, but if the whacky stuff when down further (which it could), things would become illegible. Oddly enough, that question is related to this one :)

Comment: @DMGregory I took the liberty to add actual example, with the user card.

Comment: ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้

Comment: Are "whacky" characters in fact used for some script? Is this a request to ban Moonspeak names? If US-ASCII was good enough for Jesus, it's good enough for me!

Answer (score 7):

I'm not really against stripping character sets that are used exclusively for escaping the normal bounding box of the text - that seems reasonable. Does anyone have an actual programmatic filter for these characters? You can easily eat a day finding all of the unicode that offends.

Comment: Don't you have something in the spam filters, e.g. the Chinese characters?

Comment: `/[\u0300-\u036f\u0483-\u0489\u064b-\u065f\u0670\u0E31\u0E34-\u0E3A\u0E47-\u0E4E]{3,}//g` - or sth like that from [here](https://github.com/Zarel/Pokemon-Showdown/commit/aa5b659cac924e60c8cf4820d8c7c82e89232428) under MIT license.