# How can one get an inverted username on the Stack Exchange network?

Tags: support, display-names

I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43693795/how-to-check-method-exists-in-c-sharp-with-certain-particular-signature#43693795) on Stack Overflow and saw the poster's name. It's mirrored on both x and y axis. The real name should be **Chandan** but actually it's this way

[image: screenshot of inverted name]

How is this possible?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995340/how-does-u%CA%8Dop-%C7%9Dp%E1%B4%89sdn-text-work

Comment: I'm not sure if a question about the workings of Unicode, is actually _on-topic_ here.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal What makes you think that it shouldn't be allowed, and for what reason actually?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: First we are not programmed/evolved to read English that way. Second, its difficult to write that. Third, its funny and StackExchange is no place for that.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Nicks are just personal choice. Not much to do with putting _inappropriate fun_ into post contents.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Also, you should make your question clearer about that concern. As for now you are merely asking how's that possible from a technical POV.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ no, he should ask another feature request question unless it has already been asked. I've answered the question he asked.

Comment: @Robert Yes you've answered the technical part, which is already off-topic here as I mentioned.

Comment: I disagree that it's off topic, but that's why more than one person is required to close/reopen questions I guess.

Comment: Heavily related: [Zalgo in user names and effects on comments rendering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247022/zalgo-in-user-names-and-effects-on-comments-rendering)

Comment: Amusingly - I think the question is useful so we can close other questions on this flavor of unicode abuse with this as the master question. Until The Powers that Be get fed up and we can't have nice things.

Comment: ' .    ,        -   ,     .                 .

Comment: @JasonC [too many questions to the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfaJt.jpg) :)

Comment: @alexolut Haha, sorry about that. Don't worry, [you aren't missing much](https://i.snag.gy/kPw2F5.jpg).

Comment: @JasonC another [punctuation miracle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxVYa.jpg) in the mobile chrome for iOS.

Comment: Textbook example of why this should not be allowed.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal There's no reason to disallow it globally; that'd probably actually just create more problems than it solves, mostly because it doesn't really cause problems often, it's pretty much a non-issue in reality (tbh I've *never* actually witnessed a real problem case, myself). Instead if you see a truly problematic (i.e. it breaks page formatting or something) username just flag one of that user's posts or comments and bring attention to it, a mod can rename them. (Btw, fwiw I'd actually say those are more examples that Android/iOS Unicode support could probably be improved).

Answer (score 7):

Most (but not all) Unicode characters are allowed in user names and Unicode contains [upside down and back to front versions of the Latin alphabet](http://www.fileformat.info/convert/text/upside-down-map.htm).

There are [online converters](http://www.fileformat.info/convert/text/upside-down.htm) that will take any string you type in and give you the upside down version.